# How build a Dockerfile in a Subdirectory using a Jenkinsfile

Tags: docker, jenkins, asp.net-core-2.1

I have a github repository with a declarative pipeline Jenkinsfile.
The workingdirectory on my node contains subdirectories.

The project is a simple empty linkx docker project created with visual studio 2017 and .net core 2.1. It executes on my windows 7 machine normally and has a hello world web page.

I am unable to build the Dockerfile on jenkins.
I can start the Dockerfile build using `dir(...){}`.
The failing step is always

```
COPY ["MyProject/MyProject.csproj", "MyProject/"]
```

This step requires the relative path to be in `MySolution`.

The file `Workspace/MySolution/MyProject/MyProject.csproj` exists

The error Message is that `Workspace/MyProject/MyProject.csproj` does not exist.

I searched exhaustively using google and stackoverflow. Among the things I tries are combinations of `sh` commands, `dir` syntax, options on docker build like `-f`. Some of them were straigth up failures and the best results I had ran into the `COPY` step issue.

One example of a failing step in the Jenkinsfile would be:

```
dir("MySolution/MyProject")
{
    script
    {
        docker.build("MyProject", ".")
    }
}
```

This fails with the `COPY` issue from above.

I have seen questions on so that seem to not quite apply here and which solutions did not transfer to this issue.

Comment: If you are in  `MyProject/`, then would the directory not be located at `MyProject.csproj` and not `MyProject/MyProject.csproj`? It seems the `COPY` command is pointing at the wrong location.

Comment: @MattSchuchard  yes and no - It is pointing to the correct location relative to the `Dockerfile` Everything is set up so that my local VS2017 installation compiles without error - I did not write or touch the generated `Dockerfile`. So what I need is to carefully explain to the toolchain to switch the working directory to the correct subfolder - I fail to do so repeatedly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I ended up really close to the solution of my issue.
This fixed my sub folder problem:

```
dir("MySolution")
{
    script
    {
        docker.build("MyProject", "-f ./MyProject/Dockerfile .")
    }
}
```